# How do I get the Silverlight Add-On for Visual Studio 2010 and some example code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, add-on

How do I get the Silverlight Add-On for Visual Studio 2010?

And where can I find lots of example code?

When the interent and html was new, one could find examples of how to build a website on a few trusted web sites.  The same web sites might not be the best choice for looking for examples for Silverlight, I guess.

What are the best web sites where you can look at examples -- and most importantly -- look at the source code of some examples of Silverlight?

Back when MFC existed as a option that programmers might use to develop windows applications, a coder could look at a huge list of sample code and step through that code to find something that somewhat did what he was looking for and use that example code to build his own app.  Is there anything like that for Silverlight?

I have found the http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/ Expression Blend Gallery and I have found the http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/ Silverlight dot net community samples.  I guess that will keep me busy for a while.  Are there other sites?

There are video instructions on MSDN's Channel9:
http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/curso-silverlight-4/
Are there any videos in English?  The video instructions look very good.  Where is the links to the English versions?

I was suggested this site for learning silverlight: http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/

This online documentation mentions "The Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010" which "is an add-on for Visual Studio 2010 that provides tooling for Microsoft Silverlight 4 and WCF RIA Services. It can be installed on top of either Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 Express"  where can I find this?  Is it shipped with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=902a7539-c4b5-4e54-b4c9-1432daabe1e8&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Scott Gu's blog post on the VS 2010 Silverlight Tools?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/17/silverlight-4-tools-for-vs-2010-and-wcf-ria-services-released.aspx

I recommend subscribing to his tweets (scottgu) as well as that of Team Silverlight (teamsilverlight).  Lots of good info comes through.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the SL4 tools for VS2010 is from the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), which will also list other Silverlight tools (e.g. WCF RIA Services toolkit, the latest SL4 toolkit from CodePlex) and will even help you set up IIS if you need it.

For samples, in addition to the sites you listed, some other good choices are:

1. http://www.silverlightshow.net/
2. The [Silverlight Cream](http://www.silverlightcream.com/) aggregator

Answer (score 0):

This got things set up so that I can use Visual Studio 2010 to make Silverlight apps:
[How do I get the Silverlight Add-On for Visual Studio 2010 and some example code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869483/how-do-i-get-the-silverlight-add-on-for-visual-studio-2010-and-some-example-code)